# Implement user authentication with node.js without .ejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Is there a way to implement user authentication with node.js (or something like it) into a html/css/js project without using .ejs files?

Can't find something on the internet about it, but it should be possible? Could someone direct me in the right way?

Comment: There are a ton of ways to handle authentication, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Maybe look into http://www.passportjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Passport.js's other authentication packages, but I'm pretty sure their JWT authentication package https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt doesn't require the use of template engines such as ejs.